# Different website logos for different incomming (masked) urls

Tags: php, dns, image-masking

some help would be great!

Domain **ABC1.com** shows an **image ABC1**. How can I make it so that it shows **image ABC2** when domain **ABC2.com** **forwards**, with **masking**, to ABC1.com?

Basically, the website should change its branding based on the domain name from which it originated.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the referrer to set a variable that is echoed as the base name of the file.  Something like:

```
 <?php

//check to see if referrer is set
if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])){

    //if referrer is set, evaluate to see if it matches a specified site.  plug in desired where somewebsite appears in quotes in the following line
    if($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] == 'somewebsite'){

        //set baseName for first website
        $baseName = "base1";
    }
    else if($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] == 'somewebsite'){

        //set baseName for second website
        $baseName = "base2";
    }

    //evaluate as many websites in this manner as you'd like        

    //set baseName value if http referrer does not match any specified site
    else{
        $baseName = "basenone";
    }
}

//set baseName value if no HTTP_REFERER

else{
    $baseName = "basenotset";
}

//echo baseName as first part of logo filename.  note that for this solution to work, you will have to name your logo files base1_logo.jpg, base2_logo, ... $basenone_logo  

echo "<img src=\"".$baseName."_logo.jpg.\">";
echo '<a href="test.php">TEST</a>'; 
echo "<p>".$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];

?>
```

Comment: Works Perfect !! ... thanks for spelling out ALL the code!!! and thank you again for such a fast answer :) ... cant vote you up yet it seems ... i dont have the status yet :(